# How to set bold true for some row in TableView JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I have `TableView<TypeReport> tv` and column

```
tc_name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
```

I want rows to be bold if date in cell of `tc_name` does not starts with `" "`.

I use:

```
tv.setRowFactory(new Callback<TableView<TypeReport>, TableRow<TypeReport>>() {
    @Override
    public TableRow<TypeReport> call(TableView<TypeReport> param) {
        return new TableRow<TypeReport>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(TypeReport item, boolean empty) {
                if (item==null) {
                    setStyle("");
                } else  {
                    String res=item.getName();
                    if (res.startsWith(" ")){}
                    else
                        setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
```

When I open app, required rows are bold, but when I scroll, some differ rows are bold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the style for rows whose item's name starts with `" "`. (Note you also need to call `super.updateItem(...)`):

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(TypeReport item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (item==null) {
        setStyle("");
    } else  {
        String res=item.getName();
        if (res.startsWith(" ")) {
            setStyle("");
        } else
            setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
    }

}
```

or, equivalently (but with less code):

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(TypeReport item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (item==null || item.getName().startsWith(" ")) {
        setStyle("");
    } else  {
        setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
    }

}
```

Comment: This seems broken now with JavaFX 11.0.2 - can someone confirm?